# Google Apps Script send post request to phpMailer using UrlFetchApp

Tags: php, email, google-apps-script, phpmailer

I would like to send data with UrlFetchApp but something is not working. I not understand where is the problem are not very experienced in question, can someone explain to me how to configure both files to send and receive parameters?

Google Apps Script:

```
function sendEXTmail(name,email,subject,body) {

   var url = "http://www.mysite.com/willy.php";
   var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": {
      "From_Name": "Fix Name",
      "From_Email": "fix_mail@domain.com",
      "To_Name": name,
      "To_Email": email,
      "Subject": subject,
      "Message": body
      }
   };
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   return response;
}
```

PHP:

```
require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";


$from_name = (isset($_POST['From_Name'])) ? $_POST['From_Name'] : '';
$from_email = (isset($_POST['From_Email'])) ? $_POST['From_Email'] : '';
$to_name = (isset($_POST['To_Name'])) ? $_POST['To_Name'] : '';
$to_email = (isset($_POST['To_Email'])) ? $_POST['To_Email'] : '';
$subject = (isset($_POST['Subject'])) ? $_POST['Subject'] : '';
$message = (isset($_POST['Message'])) ? $_POST['Message'] : '';

$mail= new PHPmailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "none";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
$mail->addReplyTo($from_email, $from_name);
$mail->From       = $from_email;
$mail->FromName   = $from_name;
$mail->addAddress($to_email, $to_name);
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->Body = '<html>'.$message.'</html>';


if(!$mail->Send()){ 
  echo $mail->ErrorInfo; 
}else{ 
  echo 'Email inviata correttamente!';
}
$mail->SmtpClose();
unset($mail);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is it not sending email? Is it not returning data? If it is not sending email, do you actually have an SMTP server running on localhost that can send email?

Answer (score 0):

On the Google Apps Script side, you can review the message to be sent by using `UrlFetchApp.getRequest()`. For example:

```
   // Log readable JSON object
   Logger.log( 
     JSON.stringify(
       UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url,options),
       null, 2 ));
```

Here's what it logs:

```
[15-05-06 22:23:35:144 EDT] {
  "headers": {
    "X-Forwarded-For": "99.224.168.137"
  },
  "useIntranet": false,
  "followRedirects": true,
  "payload": "From_Name=Fix+Name&Subject=subject_param&Message=body&From_Email=fix_mail@domain.com&To_Email=email@example.com&To_Name=name_param",
  "method": "post",
  "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "validateHttpsCertificates": true,
  "url": "http://www.example.com/willy.php"
}
```

Based on that, it appears that your function has prepared a POST request that should match your PHP.

Next, check the result of the POST itself. To that, first use the `muteHttpExceptions` option, then look for and handle the return code in your function by using [`HttpResponse.getResponseCode()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getResponseCode()). Furthermore, to obtain the readable text from the response, use `response.getContentText()`. Here's how that might look:

```
function sendEXTmail(name,email,subject,body) {
   name = name || "name_param";
   email = email || "email@example.com";
   subject = subject || "subject_param";
   body = body || "body";

   var url = "http://www.example.com/willy.php";
   var options = {
      "muteHttpExceptions": true,
      "method": "post",
      "payload": {
      "From_Name": "Fix Name",
      "From_Email": "fix_mail@domain.com",
      "To_Name": name,
      "To_Email": email,
      "Subject": subject,
      "Message": body
      }
   };

   // Log readable JSON object
   Logger.log( 
     JSON.stringify(
       UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url,options),
       null, 2 )); 

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

   var rc = response.getResponseCode();
   if (rc !== 200) {
     // Failure - log it
     Logger.log( "Error %s: %s", rc, response.getContentText())
   }

   return response.getContentText();
}
```

Try this with your real URL, and see what you get back. If it's a `200`, then the Google Apps Script side of the exchange has worked properly. If not, the response should tell you more about the nature of the failure, and help you along to a solution.